# How do I write multiple lists into their own column in a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text-files

I have five lists I need to make into a text file each in their own column. So far I have

```
with open("PR.txt","w") as f:
    PR = [[Velocity], [Angle], [Impact], [y], [Distance]]
    for (x) in zip(PR):
        f.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\n".format(*x))
```

I want it to write a text file that goes

```
Velocity Angle Impact y Distance
Velocity Angle Impact y Distance
Velocity Angle Impact y Distance
```

and so on

I can not figure out how to do this.

Comment: What is the purpose of `zip`? Also why do you store `PR` items in lists?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I have been looking up different ways and trying anything. I just need to make multiple lists into a text file with their own columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have all the five lists of the same length,

```
with open("PR.txt","w") as f:
 f.write("Velocity\tAngle\tImpact\ty\tDistance") 
 for i in range(0, len(Velocity)):
    # Velocity here is the list
    f.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\n".format(Velocity[i],Angle[i], Impact[i], y[i], Distance[i]))
```

Comment: This outputted the correct format and almost all my numbers correct except a few thank you.

Comment: It worked completely now thank you. I upvoted your answer but I do not have enough reputation for it to show sorry.

Comment: @DominicCasamatta Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *args to unpack the columns into `zip`:

```py
# test input
pr = [['v 0', 'v 1', 'v 2', 'v 3', 'v 4'], ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'], ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], ['y0', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'], ['dist 0', 'dist 1', 'dist 2', 'dist 3', 'dist 4']]

with open('file.txt', 'w') as fh:
    cols = ['Velocity', 'Angle', 'Impact', 'y', 'Distance']
    fh.write('\t'.join(cols) + '\n')

    # here is where you unpack everything
    for row in zip(*pr):
        fh.write('\t'.join(row) + '\n')
```

Which outputs

```
Velocity    Angle   Impact  y   Distance
v 0         10      0       y0  dist 0
v 1         11      1       y1  dist 1
v 2         12      2       y2  dist 2
v 3         13      3       y3  dist 3
v 4         14      4       y4  dist 4
```